# Как в Django models задать для поля varchar признак binary?

Tags: mysql, python, django, orm

Вот такая конструкция:

```
sbSorterTree = models.CharField(
    max_length=64,
    blank=True,
    default=""
    unique=False,
    db_index=True,
    verbose_name=u"Сортировщик деревьев",
    help_text=u"Служебное поле"
)
```

Создает вот такое поле:

```
sbSorterTree varchar(64) NOT NULL
```

а нужно чтобы создало:

```
sbSorterTree varchar(64) BINARY NOT NULL
```

Как такое сделать? Собственно задача сделать чтобы индекс по полю строился по принципу текстового поля (т.е. "124" в сортировке раньше "89") и в него можно было записывать произвольные символы (даже нечитаемые) и регистр не влиял на сортировку.

Answer (score 4):

Напишите [собственное поле](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#useful-methods)

```
class BinaryCharField(models.CharField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return super(BinaryCharField, self).db_type(connection) + ' binary'

sbSorterTree = models.BinaryCharField(
    # ...
)
```

В результате получается sql:

```
ADD COLUMN "test" varchar(64) binary;
```

То есть цель достигнута

Comment: Добавлю ссылку на русскоязычную документацию. http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/howto/custom-model-fields.html

Comment: Спасибо. Читаю эту часть доки... но пока не очень понятно. :(

Answer (score 2):

Добавленное в модель ExampleTable поле **sbSorterTree**

```
class ExampleTable(models.Model):
    sbSorterTree = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, default="", unique=False, db_index=True, verbose_name=u"Сортировщик деревьев", help_text=u"Служебное поле")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'example_table'
```

создает такую миграцию:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ExampleTable',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('sbSorterTree', models.CharField(blank=True, db_index=True, default='', help_text='Служебное поле', max_length=64, verbose_name='Сортировщик деревьев')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'example_table',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

и такой sql:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model ExampleTable
--
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `sbSorterTree` varchar(64) NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX `example_table_479ea2e4` ON `example_table` (`sbSorterTree`);

COMMIT;
```

Вы можете добавить [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) команду в файл миграций и промигрировать, пример:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ExampleTable',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('sbSorterTree', models.CharField(blank=True, db_index=True, default='', help_text='Служебное поле', max_length=64, verbose_name='Сортировщик деревьев')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'example_table',
            },
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE example_table MODIFY COLUMN sbSorterTree varchar(64) BINARY NOT NULL;"),
    ]
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что это не спортивно, но не проще тогда руками залезть с базу и через ALTER TABLE назначить полю BINARY? Django ничего не заметит (ей все равно) а все заработает как запланировано...

Comment: Предпочитаю делать через RunSQL, что бы была история и эти запросы смог выполнить, к примеру, неопытный разработчик в рамках миграции на локальном проекте.